# Thank you for "the" comment. or Thank you for "your" comment

Tags: word-difference, determiners

A question. In spoken American English, do you feel different if I say as below?

1. Thank you for "the" comment.
2. Thank you for "your" comment.

If I say your, does that sound repetitious?

Comment: I think both mean the same when answering someone's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are equally fine. And "Thank you for your comment" is quite common and doesn't sound repetitive at all. In fact, although I can't provide any evidence nor can I explain this, but it feels to me that the version with "your" is even more frequent than the version with "the". It sounds more specific in some way.